# Android Retrofit set variable dynamically to Route

Tags: android, parameters, routes, retrofit, retrofit2

I Try to set a dynamic variable defined as static variable in a package Route but I dont understand how it works with Retrofit.

import static de.package.tradilianz.DashboardRetailer.retailerid;

public interface APIInterface {

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("retailers/{param}/products")
Call<Product> createProduct(@Body Product product @Param("param") id = retailerid);
```

}

How to set {param} correctly? I thought I Could write the retailerid as static String and import in to my Interface Class and declare it to @Param but it wont work. I Want to tell that id = retailerId should set in @POST("retailers/{param}/products"}

I also tried to set @POST("retailers/"+retailerid+"/products") But the variable must be a constant. Well I get the variable retailerid in Activity I dont have any constants yet.

My Activity class:

```
public class RetailerProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static String id;
    APIInterface apiInterface;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retailer_product);
        context = this;
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        //Get retailerIdfrom SharedPreference
        String serializedDataFromPreference = prefs.getString("RetailerResponseObject", null);
        Retailer retailer = Retailer.create(serializedDataFromPreference);
        id = retailer.getId();
    }

    public void onClickProduct(View v){
        apiInterface = APIClient.getClient(ipAddress).create(APIInterface.class);

        Product product = new Product("994", "Marlboro", "Marlborolight", 8.5, "Tabakwaren",
                "1");
        // POST  product
        Call<Product> call1 = apiInterface.createProduct(product);
        call1.enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, Response<Product> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    try{
                        Product prodct1 = response.body();
                        Log.w("Der Response body",prodct1.toString() );

                        //speichern in sharedPrefence fehlt
                    }catch (NullPointerException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Erreiche den Server nicht :/! Wurde der Server gestartet?",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Product> call,Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
                Log.w("onResponse: ", "POST Response probleme", t.getCause());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

You have Ideas guys pls help

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `@Path()` instead of `@Param()`

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("retailers/{param}/products")
Call<Product> createProduct(@Body Product product, @Path("param") String value);

// Inside you onClickProduct just pass your value.
Call<Product> call1 = apiInterface.createProduct(product,"Put you Value Here");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dynamic URL like this:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST
Call<Product> createProduct(@Url String URL, @Body Product product);
```

Comment: Hi Jassem Ben Hamida, Thank you it worked for me! Probs :)

Comment: great! Welcome :D